# Weird network behavior, Webserver is stopped but still can reach the file

Tags: nginx, web-server, cache

I downloaded the file `dl.example.com/10mg.test` once. And suddenly I noticed even without webserver running (`service nginx stop`) I can still reach the file.

How is this even possible ? No matter how many times I try, I can still reach the file and download it to full content. And there is no connection alive when I check using `netstat --tcp` and no traffic change in `ifconfig`

Tried renaming the file, still can download it. Also tried changing browser.

Is there a possibility that the ISP cached the file ?

note : the `10mg.test` file is the cachefly test file that I downloaded to server using `wget`

**UPDATE 1**: Tried shutting down the server, Still can download the file...

**UPDATE 2**: Seems I can't reach the file anymore. Not sure if it's because the server is completely down and I gave it some time. Even if it was caused by any other running process, why I couldn't see any change in `ifconfig` TX/RX value, neither in `netstat --tcp`

**UPDATE 3**: After rebooting the server, I renamed the file name and used `watch ifconfig` to watch over TX rate. Then started downloading file with different browsers and devices, and still There is no change in TX rate after the file has been downloaded once.

Comment: shut the http server down and access the site from a device you have never accessed it from (ie your phone). if it still comes up you either have some sort of proxy cache server running or a second instance of an http server

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you control `dl.example.com` and there are no other webservers running on that machine, the only way you can still request any content from that server is if it has been cached somewhere between your computer and your server.

try adding some query information to that url, eg: `10mg.test?q=123` and see if it still works. if it does, then you could be requesting that file from another server then your own, or there is still some form of software running on your server.

Comment: No it doesn't work when using `?q=123`. Also tried shutting down the server to make sure there is no other software involving.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because of your local browser cache.

Comment: I know that but I tried changing browser as I said in first post.

Answer (score 1):

Its likely that nginx is still running. To find out, try:

```
service nginx status
```

You may need to use sudo to stop nginx